# Extracting Aliases , maps from .rtf document

Tags: rtf

I need to extract aliases, map files and images from a rtf document? Tools doesn't work. Is it possible with a vb.net coding process?

Comment: What is your exact programming question. Please refer to the Help Center to learn more about good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I need to convert a win help project to htmlhelp project. As a first step I need to decompile the winhelp project(.hlp) to extract (.hpj), rtf, images, maps and aliases. But it’s not working with winhelp decompiler tool. What are the other options?

Comment: Maybe you can ask your question on other stack exchange web sites. I don't know if [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) can help you